# Grid view Cell returns wrong output

Tags: asp.net, gridview

First you see my GridView

[image]

Now see Row 5 (Thu).There I have a date 1/1/2015 and also have a link button like Click to add.When I click on `Click to add` of 5th row am getting the values of row 4. Again I click on 6th row button I am getting the value of 5th row.Why it happened like this ? If I make any mistake please help me to solve it. I removed my databound event, Then I get the expected output after adding these event I am getting wrong output.So problem is my Databound function. How can I solve it?

My Cell click event is

```
 protected void lnkmonth1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        string id = grdAcademicCalender.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        Label lbldate = (Label)row.FindControl("lbldates1");

        if (lbldate.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(lbldate.Text);
            txtdate.Text = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            ModalPopupExtender3.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            ModalPopupExtender4.Show();
        }
        bindgridHeader();
        bindgrid();
    }
```

I have an DataBound

```
   protected void grdAcademicCalender_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableHeaderCell cell0 = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell cell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell cell2 = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell cell3 = new TableHeaderCell();

        cell0.Text = "Days";
        cell0.ColumnSpan = 0;
        cell0.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F5BCA9");
        row.Controls.Add(cell0);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblmonth1.Text))//January 2015
        {
            cell1.Text = lblmonth1.Text;
            cell1.ColumnSpan = 3;
            cell1.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F5BCA9");
            row.Controls.Add(cell1);
        }
        else
        {
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblmonth2.Text))//February 2015
        {
            cell2.Text = lblmonth2.Text;
            cell2.ColumnSpan = 3;
            cell2.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F5BCA9");
            row.Controls.Add(cell2);
        }
        else
        {
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblmonth3.Text))//March 2015
        {
            cell3.Text = lblmonth3.Text;
            cell3.ColumnSpan = 3;
            cell3.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F5BCA9");
            row.Controls.Add(cell3);
        }
     grdAcademicCalender.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
}
```

My aspx is

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdAcademicCalender" Width="1500"  runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Wheat" PageSize="40" DataKeyNames="ID"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="false" OnDataBound="grdAcademicCalender_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="grdAcademicCalender_RowDataBound" >
      <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>        
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblshortdate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ShortName") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbldates1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Dates1") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>       
         <asp:Label ID="lblmonth1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MonthNumber1") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>       
         <asp:Linkbutton ID="lblevent1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EventField1") %>'></asp:Linkbutton>
         <asp:Linkbutton ID="lnkmonth1" Width="140" runat="server" OnClick="lnkmonth1_Click" Text="Click to add"></asp:Linkbutton>
      </ItemTemplate>

       </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

if it is difficult to do, then help me to get the cell2 value when I click on cell1 (Incremented cell values).

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. Are you getting `lbldate` & `id` wrong?

Comment: @Rahul Singh & MrsEd , Kindly find my updated question